# Ceiling fan replacement wiring issues

Tags: wiring, ceiling, ceiling-fan

I am replacing a ceiling fan (old fan had wall switches (1) for light (1) for fan).  The new fan also has a light but has a wireless remote too. My issue is that the old fan used, black, white, blue, & green wires. The new fan motor only uses black & white wires.

So I can not use the wall light switch and fan wall switch to control the fan I have to use the remote. I want to use the wall switch to turn fan on/off and the fan switch to turn the fan on/off.

Can I somehow use my wall switches to my new fan. The box to the fan has all the wires the fan doesn't. Can I add a blue wire to the light fixture thru the fan?
Install instructions: http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/836071007989_install.pdf

Comment: Can you post the instructions that came with your new fan, or a make and model for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

### Return your fan and get a better fan

What you have discovered is one of the main reasons cheap ceiling fans with built-in remote receivers are a bad deal in the long run: the packaged receiver is designed based on the assumption that that's the only way you'll ever control the ceiling fan.

So, I'd take this fan back to where you got it from and get a better fan that supports separate fan and light wall switches instead -- you'll be glad you did in the long run.